# Update quantity from Prestashop Database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, inner-join, prestashop-1.6

I have a little problem to UPDATE the Prestashop database.
I try to update the quantity from ps_stock_available.
I have 2 quantity to update. My INNER JOIN work.

```
id_product   id_product_attribute   upc           quantity
140          263                    90100014017   665
```

but with the upc, I also need to get the id_product to update an other id_product_attribute with 0 :

```
id_product   id_product_attribute   upc           quantity
140          0                      90100014017   675
```

SQL:

```
UPDATE ps_stock_available AS s
INNER JOIN ps_product_attribute AS ps ON ps.id_product_attribute = s.id_product_attribute
INNER JOIN ps_product AS p ON p.id_product = ps.id_product
SET s.quantity = s.quantity-1
WHERE ps.upc = 90100014017
```

It's work to update the first quantity, but I don'y know how to update the second quantity. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution !

```
SELECT sa.id_product, sa.id_product_attribute, sa.quantity, pa.upc
FROM ps_stock_available AS sa
LEFT OUTER JOIN ps_product_attribute AS pa ON pa.id_product_attribute = sa.id_product_attribute
WHERE sa.id_product = 140;
```